# Turn undefined to 0 by default

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, undefined

I want my undefined code to automatically change so it shows as 0, how can I do this?

Comment: You have an XSS vulnerability.

Comment: Oh, really? What is it :P

Comment: @Crogan You are directly manipulating your HTML. That is not safe at all.

Comment: I see, Im kinda new to this

Answer (score 2):

You can check whether it is `undefined` or not. Simply doing the following:

```
if(typeof value.displayName === 'undefined') {
    value.displayName = 0;
}
```

Comment: It comes up as Undefined out of 0 Macs Available and I just want it to say 0 out of 0. :P

Comment: you can also do the similar checking to both `value.availPCs` and `value.numPCs`

Comment: It's still undefined when I try ;/ I tried with value.availMacs which is what im trying to change but it wont budge. Heres a screenshot http://prntscr.com/f509nh

Answer (score 0):

Replace `value.availMacs` with `(value.availMacs || 0)`